# BeautifulSoupのfind_allで子要素は取得しない方法

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

beautifulsoup4==4.10.0
python==3.9.10

といった実行環境で行っています。

```
<tr align="center">
<td bgcolor="#b0c4de" width="20%">作品名</td>
  <th width="80%"><a href="" name="times_auto-tag">ULTRAMAN</a></th>
</tr>
<tr align="center">
<td bgcolor="#b0c4de" width="20%">放送形態</td>
  <th width="80%">配信</th>
</tr>
```

といった構造のときに`td`タグの中身だけで， 子要素のthタグを除いたtextを取り出したいときのコードをご教示いただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<tr align="center">
<td bgcolor="#b0c4de" width="20%">作品名</td>
  <th width="80%"><a href="" name="times_auto-tag">ULTRAMAN</a></th>
</tr>
<tr align="center">
<td bgcolor="#b0c4de" width="20%">放送形態</td>
  <th width="80%">配信</th>
</tr> 
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
result = [i.text for i in soup.select('td')]

print(result)

#
['作品名', '放送形態']
```